# How to determine if a contour is a circular arc or not in openCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I have various types of different contours in my image represented by different colours and want to filter them on the basis of the contours being a circular arc. I don't know the centre or the radius(which I need to find) of the arc as it is changing from contour to contour and hence need a way to filter the contours(in this case for the red, green, and blue contours) so as to reduce the data set on which to run polyfit for a circle. I am using OpenCV on python. Can anyone please help.

Comment: please share some images and codes

Comment: open cv houghs circle transform